# Python/Django: Custom user model doesn't get saved to database when submitting a form

Tags: python, django, database, forms, model

so I am experimenting with custom user models in Django for a school project.
I created some custom fields inheriting from the AbstractUser class, wrote a custom UserManager and registered the model in the admin page, finally rendering a template from a form which extends the UserCreationForm and uses my CustomUser as a model(which all seems to work fine, all the fields are visible in the admin, also in adding and detail view). Also I can add users directly from the admin page, that is working fine.

However, when I submit the form, I get redirected and get `[26/Jul/2023 13:10:40] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0` in the terminal but the user is not saved in the database.

Following you can find my files.

models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, birth_date, credit_card, **extra_fields):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, birth_date=birth_date, credit_card=credit_card)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_staff=True."))
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_superuser=True."))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    birth_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    credit_card = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django import forms

class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField
    birth_date = forms.DateField()
    credit_card = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'birth_date', 'credit_card', 'password1', 'password2')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

# Register your models here.

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff',
        'birth_date', 'credit_card',
        )
    
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('username', 'password')
        }),
        ('Personal info', {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        }),
        ('Permissions', {
            'fields': (
                'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                'groups', 'user_permissions'
                )
        }),
        ('Important dates', {
            'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')
        }),
        ('Additional info', {
            'fields': ('birth_date', 'credit_card')
        })
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
        }),
        ('Personal info', {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        }),
        ('Permissions', {
            'fields': (
                'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                'groups', 'user_permissions'
                )
        }),
        ('Important dates', {
            'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')
        }),
        ('Additional info', {
            'fields': ('birth_date', 'credit_card')
        })
    )


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import RegisterUserForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

def register_user(request):
    form = RegisterUserForm

    if request.POST:
        form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect(test)

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)


def test(request):
    return HttpResponse('TEST!')
```

index.html

```
<h3>Register User</Form></h3>
<hr>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Inside settings.py I included `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'`

After submitting the form, no errors occur but the user is simply not stored to the database.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: * return redirect(test): I guess this is wrong, because you have to redirect to a model, view name or url (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
* I dont know if the form is valid, but you can try and `raise ValueError(form.is_valid())` to see what the result is, if you don't have a debugger
* You can also `raise ValueError(form.errors)` to see what the errors are. 
But again, I would suggest you use a debugger (pycharm or vscode are both eay to be set up)

Answer (score 0):

Cool for me remove all the fields you have included in the form since you're CustomUser inherit from AbstractUser so you have

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django import forms

class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = CustomUser
fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', '

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).